# casting issue with realpath function (c programming)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, warnings, realpath

When I compile the following code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#define _ISOC99_SOURCE
#define __EXTENSIONS__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *symlinkpath = argv[1];
    char actualpath [PATH_MAX];
    char *ptr;
    ptr = realpath(symlinkpath, actualpath);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
}
```

I get a warning on the line that contains the call to the realpath function, saying:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Anybody know what's up? I'm running Ubuntu Linux 9.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple. Glibc treats realpath() as a GNU extension, not POSIX. So, add this line:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

... prior to including stdlib.h so that it is prototyped and known to to return `char *`. Otherwise, gcc is going to assume it returns the default type of `int`. The prototype in stdlib.h is not seen unless `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined.

The following complies fine without warnings with -Wall passed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *symlinkpath = argv[1];
    char actualpath [PATH_MAX];
    char *ptr;
    ptr = realpath(symlinkpath, actualpath);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

You will see similar behavior with other popular extensions such as asprintf(). Its worth a look at /usr/include/ to see exactly how much that macro turns on and what it changes.

Comment: Actually you should read `man feature_test_macros`.  Also, the manpages for `realpath`, `asprintf`, etc. all tell which macros must be present for their declaration.

Comment: @ephemient: The headers are the documentation when it comes to altering the behavior of the standard C library. Call me paranoid, but errata happens in documentation updates from release to release. Sometimes things are incorrect, sometimes changes don't creep into documentation .. sometimes new changes are documented incorrectly. I know studying glibc has been known to make heads explode, but its worth a look at the headers. You need to know what each macro actually _does_ , which is best obtained via grep and other means.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know what `realpath` is, so it assumes it's a function returning int.  It does this for historical reasons: a lot of older C programs relied on it doing this.

You're probably missing the declaration of it, e.g. by forgetting to `#include` its header file.

Comment: Yup, put an stdlib include at the top.

Comment: No, including stdlib doesn't make it go away

Comment: I know, now all I need to do is figure out what it is :)

Is there any other information I could provide which would be helpful?

Comment: in glibc, realpath() is an extension.