# C realpath return NULL vector, can't find the path

Tags: c, realpath

I wanted a function to return the absolute path given a relative path to an existing file.
Searching online I came across realpath here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/229038/19637794
And followed the example here: [Example of realpath function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563168/example-of-realpath-function-in-c)

So I wrote:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char path[PATH_MAX];

void test(void){
char *ppath = realpath("../../test/src/file", path );
if (ppath != NULL)
{
    *do stuff, read the file*
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
free(ppath);
}

int main ()
{
    test();
}
```

Where my working directories are as follow

```
dir
|---CMakeLists.txt
|---build/
|   |---test/
|       |
|       |---executable
|
|---test/
|   |---CMakeLists.txt
|   |---src/
|       |
|       |---test.c
|       |---file
```

I launched the executable from `build` directory with `./test/executable` but I kept getting `-1`, checked with gdb and verified that `ppath` was `0x0`.

I read [My realpath return null for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550771/my-realpath-return-null-for-files)
But didn't seem to fit my problem

Then I read about `#include <errno.h>`, so added this two line and it said `"No such file or directory"`

```
else
{
    char* errStr = strerror(errno);
    printf("%s" ,errStr);
}
```

After that I added `printf("%s", path);` that returned: `dir/test`, which is the directory above the one I wanted, still `ppath` is `NULL`.
I tried to add a file in the directory above, but doesn't seem to work either, nor with its original path nor with the new one.

I also read it might happen having `realpath` returning `NULL` if the path exceed the maximum allowed in phase of declaration, so I also tried to remove path and feeding `NULL`, like it was done at https://www.demo2s.com/c/c-char-real-realpath-p-null.html as follow:

```
char *ppath = realpath("../../test/src/file", NULL );
```

Which didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: few modify based on comment
Edit2: added parenthesis between test and ;

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: Unless the second argument passed to realpath() (char *restrict resolved_path) is NULL, you should not be calling free() on the returned pointer, since it will not have been dynamically allocated.

Comment: You can also simplify `if (ppath != NULL) ...` to `if (ppath) ...`

Comment: The code appears to be missing a `main` function. "I kept getting errors" ... what errors? For what code?

Comment: @WillEccles from the build directory I run ./test/executable

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl Right, I'll try without the free.
Yes, absolutely, but I prefer not to simplify the expression inside the if, to make it 100% clear what was the risk in the operation.

Comment: @thrig I'm trying to automate tests for a function to read files (function that compile correctly, and if I gave it the absolute path "by hand" work as desired). 
In order to do that I have a function where I call realpath as posted, if the pointer isn't NULL it should read the file calling the function under test, else I return -1.
In main I call the function so what I expected was the function under test to read the file, insted I keep receiving -1, because the pointer is NULL; which is the errors I was referring to. I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: `test;` does not do anything. To call the function, you need `test();`. Edit the question to provide an actual working [mre].

Comment: @cielocamminatore perfectly understandable, clear code is often better than slightly condensed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment says "*from the build directory I run ./test/executable*", the present working directory is "dir/build". Starting from this directory, `realpath()` is right telling you that there is no "dir/build/../../test/src/file".